# Xcode: replace a file that is under SVN version control

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, terminal, commit

I have an xcode project that is under svn version control. Through XCode, I deleted some files and then replaced them with updated ones. Now SVN has marked the files with a 'D' which obviously means marked for deletion. But I am not sure if the new files will be included in my next commit, or if only the deletion will be committed?

Comment: Can you try making your commit outside of Xcode so you have full control?

Comment: Yes I can do that. But my worry is not whether I can commit or not. Its where the commit will include the new files or not. Running svn add fileName simply marks the files as 'RM' and not 'A', which still leaves me wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best way to do so is through finder. I first reverted my changes using `svn revert -R`. Then I replaced the files through finder. When I hit svn status, it showed a few files as modified. These are the files where there were differences to the ones that I deleted. The files that did not have any differences did not appear on the status list. Now I can safely commit.